# Forex Python inconsistent rates

Tags: python, forex

I'm getting inconsistent results from the Python Forex package:

```
from forex_python.converter import CurrencyRates, get_rate
from datetime import datetime
rate_list = []
for i in range(10):
    rate_list.append(get_rate('EUR', 'USD', datetime(2021, 1, 12)))
print(set(rate_list))
{1.1304, 1.2161}
```

Since I'm always fetching the same rate on the same date, I would expect that `rate_list` will consist of only 1 unique element. Is this a known issue or am I missing something?

Comment: Perhaps the two numbers refer to the bid and ask prices?

Comment: At each iteration I am only getting one number. It would be very weird if the function decided to randomly return the bid price some times, and the ask price other times.

Comment: I noticed that sending API calls to https://theforexapi.com/api/2021-12-01/?base=EUR can randomly return wrong results (for example, it returned the right result 3 times, but for the 4th time it returned the results for 2020-04-30). This seems very weird to me.